# How do I Implement Ignore Code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, api

I pretty much got everything work on this python script and one this is missing.
This script follows the users in the list according to given time day, but how to ignore the followed (already followed) user from the list immediately?

```
import datetime

import logging
import random
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import sys

import time
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Timer


class InstaBot:

    url = 'https://www.instagram.com/'
    url_follow = 'https://www.instagram.com/web/friendships/%s/follow/'
    url_unfollow = 'https://www.instagram.com/web/friendships/%s/unfollow/'
    url_login = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/'
    url_logout = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/logout/'
    url_media_detail = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/%s/?__a=1'
    url_user_detail = 'https://www.instagram.com/%s/?__a=1'

    user_agent = ("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 "
                  "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36")
    accept_language = 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4'

    # If instagram ban you - query return 400 error.
    error_400 = 0
    # If you have 3 400 error in row - looks like you banned.
    error_400_to_ban = 3

    # Log setting.
    log_file_path = ''
    log_file = 0

    # Other.
    user_id = 0

    # For new_auto_mod
    next_iteration = {"Like": 0, "Follow": 0, "Unfollow": 0, "Comments": 0}

    def __init__(self,
                 login,
                 password,
                 proxy="",
                 ):


        self.user_login = login.lower()
        self.user_password = password
        self.log_mod = 0
        self.follow_counter=0
        self.s = requests.Session()
        # if you need proxy make something like this:
        # self.s.proxies = {"https" : "http://proxyip:proxyport"}
        # by @planet
        if proxy != "":
            proxies = {
                'http': 'http://' + proxy,
                'https': 'http://' + proxy,
            }
            self.s.proxies.update(proxies)
            # convert login to lower

        self.url_user_info = "https://www.instagram.com/%s/?__a=1"

    def get_user_id_by_login(self, user_name):
        url_info = self.url_user_info % (user_name)
        info = self.s.get(url_info)
        all_data = json.loads(info.text)
        id_user = all_data['user']['id']
        return id_user

    def login(self):
        log_string = 'Trying to login as %s...\n' % (self.user_login)
        self.write_log(log_string)
        self.s.cookies.update({
            'sessionid': '',
            'mid': '',
            'ig_pr': '1',
            'ig_vw': '1920',
            'csrftoken': '',
            's_network': '',
            'ds_user_id': ''
        })
        self.login_post = {
            'username': self.user_login,
            'password': self.user_password
        }
        self.s.headers.update({
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
            'Accept-Language': self.accept_language,
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Content-Length': '0',
            'Host': 'www.instagram.com',
            'Origin': 'https://www.instagram.com',
            'Referer': 'https://www.instagram.com/',
            'User-Agent': self.user_agent,
            'X-Instagram-AJAX': '1',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        })
        r = self.s.get(self.url)
        self.s.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken': r.cookies['csrftoken']})
        time.sleep(5 * random.random())
        login = self.s.post(
            self.url_login, data=self.login_post, allow_redirects=True)
        self.s.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken': login.cookies['csrftoken']})
        self.csrftoken = login.cookies['csrftoken']
        time.sleep(5 * random.random())

        if login.status_code == 200:
            r = self.s.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
            finder = r.text.find(self.user_login)
            if finder != -1:

                self.user_id = self.get_user_id_by_login(self.user_login)
                self.login_status = True
                log_string = '%s login success!' % (self.user_login)
                self.write_log(log_string)
            else:
                self.login_status = False
                self.write_log('Login error! Check your login data!')
        else:
            self.write_log('Login error! Connection error!')

    def logout(self):
        now_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        log_string = 'Logout: likes - %i, follow - %i, unfollow - %i, comments - %i.' % \
                     (self.like_counter, self.follow_counter,
                      self.unfollow_counter, self.comments_counter)
        self.write_log(log_string)
        work_time = datetime.datetime.now() - self.bot_start
        log_string = 'Bot work time: %s' % (work_time)
        self.write_log(log_string)

        try:
            logout_post = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': self.csrftoken}
            logout = self.s.post(self.url_logout, data=logout_post)
            self.write_log("Logout success!")
            self.login_status = False
        except:
            self.write_log("Logout error!")



    def follow(self, user_name):
        """ Send http request to follow """
        if self.login_status:

            urlget_id="https://www.instagram.com/%s/?__a=1"%user_name
            jsonurl = urlopen(urlget_id)
            userinfo = json.loads(jsonurl.read().decode())
            user_id=userinfo['user']['id']
            url_follow = self.url_follow % (user_id)
            try:
                follow = self.s.post(url_follow)
                if follow.status_code == 200:
                    self.follow_counter += 1
                    log_string = "Followed: %s #%i." % (user_name,
                                                        self.follow_counter)
                    self.write_log(log_string)

                return follow
            except:
                self.write_log("Except on follow!")
        return False





    def write_log(self, log_text):

        if self.log_mod == 0:
            try:
                print(log_text)
            except UnicodeEncodeError:
                print("Your text has unicode problem!")
        elif self.log_mod == 1:
            # Create log_file if not exist.
            if self.log_file == 0:
                self.log_file = 1
                now_time = datetime.datetime.now()
                self.log_full_path = '%s%s_%s.log' % (
                    self.log_file_path, self.user_login,
                    now_time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y_%H:%M"))
                formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s '
                                              '- %(message)s')
                self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.user_login)
                self.hdrl = logging.FileHandler(self.log_full_path, mode='w')
                self.hdrl.setFormatter(formatter)
                self.logger.setLevel(level=logging.INFO)
                self.logger.addHandler(self.hdrl)
            # Log to log file.
            try:
                self.logger.info(log_text)
            except UnicodeEncodeError:
                print("Your text has unicode problem!")





def followUsers(username,password,filepath,numberOfFollowersPerDay,followDelay):
    instabot = InstaBot(login=username, password=password, proxy='')
    instabot.login()
    index=0
    x = datetime.today()
    y = x.replace(day=x.day + 1, hour=1, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    delta_t = y - x
    secs = 500 + 1
    def follow(filepath,numberOfFollowersInADay,delay):
        follower=0
        with open(filepath) as f:
            content = f.readlines()
        # you may also want to remove whitespace characters like `\n` at the end of each line
        users = [x.strip() for x in content]
        while((follower<numberOfFollowersInADay) and (follower<len(users))):
            nonlocal index
            instabot.follow(users[index])
            time.sleep(delay)
            follower=follower+1
            index=index+1
        print("done for today")

    t = Timer(secs, follow(filepath,numberOfFollowersPerDay,followDelay))
    t.start()
#call followUsers with parameteres username,password,filepath,totalnumbresOfFollowin a day, follow dealay in seconds
followUsers('username','pass','C:\\Users\\rocks\\PycharmProjects\\untitled\\usernames.txt',10,30)
```

Comment: please, make [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am not familiar with that, I am looking for some help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a list of followers, and before here instabot.follow(users[index]),you need to do

```
if users[index] not in followers:
    instabot.follow(users[index])
```

Comment: I think you got it wrong of my concept. The script should ignore the followed user and continue to next one without any delay.